# how ordering by ID not randomize related product of Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce display in single product page by default a section of correlated product, it retrieve in random mode 4 product with same category or tag.

So every time you reload the page or visit the page in next day it display every time different correlated product, this is not good option for SEO, because in this way not pass link juice between pages during the time.

so i want to try to display a correlated product by sequential ID order.

from what I understand woocommerce extrapolates related products randomly through the use of the orderby = 'rand' function in the query

then tried to find a filter that could change this value in `orderby = 'ID'` or `orderby = 'post__in'` , using this snippet in function.php of theme:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_output_related_products_args', 'wh_related_products_args');

    function wh_related_products_args($args)
    { 
            $args['orderby'] = 'ID'; // or  $args['orderby'] = 'post__in';

        return $args;
    }
```

**but it does not work**

the code in related.php is that

```
<?php
/**
 * Related Products
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/related.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     3.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

if ( $related_products ) : ?>

    <section class="related products">

        <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Related products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php foreach ( $related_products as $related_product ) : ?>

                <?php
                    $post_object = get_post( $related_product->get_id() );

                    setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object );

                    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

    </section>

<?php endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in functions.php of active theme.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_related_posts','wpse_123436_change_wc_related_products_relation_to_and' );
function wpse_123436_change_wc_related_products_relation_to_and() {
   $get_related_products_args = array(
              'orderby' => 'id', // you can place id,title over here. 
              'order'     => 'ASC',
            );
   return $get_related_products_args;
}
```

Comment: not work, when reload the page i see random products in related product section every time, could be a filter priority the cause  ?

Comment: May be you are right try with 99. I checked with my system it is working fine. if priority could not resolved this issue than share your theme name and plugins list

Comment: I have updated to latest version both wordpress and woocommerce, tried with default theme, disabled all plugin, not work, are you tried with this same condition ? what version of woocommerce you have ?

Comment: 3.4.1 is my plugin version of woo-commerce. did your theme has override the related product file?

Comment: no, i have renamed the folder of woocommerce in theme, so the file are retrieved from plugin folder

Comment: do you have cache enable?

Comment: no, with cache enabled the page remain static, in my case product correlated changes every time reload the page

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_output_related_products_args', 'prefix_modify_related_products_args', 20 );
  function prefix_modify_related_products_args( $args ) {
  $args['orderby'] = 'ID';

    return $args;
}
```

Note, you can add other things, like `$args['order']`, `$args['posts_per_page']` etc. Review https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters